# Use React componentDidMount in a modal/overlay react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import { Component } from 'react'

export default class Overlay extends Component {

    static propTypes = {
       show: React.PropTypes.bool
    };

    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        const { show } = this.props;
        return (
            <div id="overlay">
                    {show &&
                        this.props.children
                    }
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Above is my overlay component, I try to not use any premade component from npm because I want to understand more about react. How can I do something after the children is rendered?

Somewhere in other component I do `<Overlay show={true} />`, now I want to do something after the children is rendered. I tried

```
componentDidMount(){
    console.log('hey');
}
```

in overlay component, it trigger first time but not after the user trigger the overlay.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [componentWillReceiveProps](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops) lifecycle method - this receives the "new" props being sent to the component so you can see if there are any changes.  It is guaranteed to be called any time the props passed to your component change, however, it may also be called when the props haven't changed, so it's necessary to manually check if the prop you are interested in has altered.

(You can also remove the constructor if you aren't doing anything in there)

```
import { Component } from 'react'

export default class Overlay extends Component {

    static propTypes = {
       show: React.PropTypes.bool
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log("The componentDidMount method is only fired the first time the component is mounted");

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        // this will run every time the props change - and possibly in addition to this, so we need to check for prop changes
        if (this.props.show !== nextProps.show) {
            console.log("The show prop changed!);
        }
    }

    render() {
        const { show } = this.props;
        return (
            <div id="overlay">
                    {show &&
                        this.props.children
                    }
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Any clue why this won't work? `document.getElementsByTagName('body').style['background']  = 'red';`

Comment: The getElementsByTagName method returns a collection of elements, so you can't directly set the style on what it returns. ([MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) are a great resource for looking up functions).  I would approach this differently... 1) Create a CSS class for red background e.g. `.overlay-background { background-color: red; }` 2) Use `document.body.classList.add('overlay-background');`